# react navigation- navigating to a new screen from an onpress function

Tags: reactjs, navigation

Hey Guys I am trying to navigate between screens. I have set up a screen called games that I am trying to get to from an on press function. When I press the image I would like to move between screens. Everything is working except it is not navigating between the screens when clicked it doesn't do anything. I am using a bottomtabnavigator and react-navigation. It works if I add the screen to the bottomtabnavigator which I dont want todo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8Z20.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WD1i.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNVGw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Normally the right way is add screens to the navigator If you dont want to use tab navigator you have to use stack navigator for that then there is no tabs in the bottom but navigation should works

[Doc for stack navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html)